# Multi-user CRUD: Valid, Problem, or Error?

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem

### [Introduction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYwVP.jpg):

Ever used Dropbox with some other people and you both modified the same file? Ever had a multi-user application with a relational database, and two people were modifying (or worse, one was deleting and the other modifying) the same object? Well, let's simulate that with this challenge (sort-of).

For the sake of this challenge, we only have two users and either one or two relevant files. Both users have in general privileges to [CRUD (Create, Read, Update, and Delete)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) all files.

### Challenge:

#### Input:

We'll have a few inputs (input format is flexible, and any reasonable format is allowed):

1) ***Locking mode (on/off)***: Kinda the difference between [optimistic and pessimistic concurrency locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_control#Categories).
Both users are allowed to CRUD (Create, Read, Update, and Delete) everything, but sometimes errors or problems can occur. Depending on the locking mode a problem when turned off, could be an error when turned on. This is explained below in the ***Output*** section.

2 & 3) ***Two user-actions***. These actions always consist of two things: What the user does (Create, Read, Update, or Delete) and for which file.

#### Output:

We'll have three possible outputs:

1. ***Valid***: Both actions by both users can be done simultaneously without any issues occurring.
2. ***Error***: Both actions by both users cannot be done simultaneously and causes an error for one of the users (which user is irrelevant for this challenge). This can occur when:

   - one user Reads or Updates a file, which the other user Deletes;
   - both users Update the same file with locking mode turned on;
   - a user Creates a file, which the other user Reads/Updates/Deletes (this means the file already exists, so it cannot be Created);
   - both users Create the same file.
3. ***Problem***: Both actions by both users can be done simultaneously, but can cause unexpected problems. This can occur when:

   - both users Update a file when locking mode is turned off;
   - one user Updates a file, which the other user Reads;
   - both users Delete the same file (practically this will causes an error for the second user, but since it will still be deleted like the user wants, it will be a problem instead of an error for the sake of this challenge)

### Challenge Rules:

- All input and output is flexible, **and everyone should state which one they've used in their answer!**
  Example inputs: `0`/`1` for locking mode & `31` (third action: Update; file: 1) & `21` (second action: Read; file: 1); `true`/`false` for locking mode & `['C','A']` (action: Create; file: A) & `['D','B']` (action: Delete; file: B); etc.
  Example outputs: `null`/`true`/`false` (null = valid; true = error; false = problem); `-1`/`0`/`1` (-1 = error; 0 = problem; 1 = valid); etc. The three possible outputs have to be **unique and distinct** for the three output-type, though.
- What the files are called is irrelevant, which can also be seen with the input-examples above. So feel free to use any type of file name in your answers consisting of a single (ASCII) letter or digit. They do have to be consistent across all your test cases however, so you can't use `A`/`B` in one test case and `1`/`2` in another.
- The four actions for CRUD have to be unique and consistent values as well. So you cannot use `'D'`/`'C'` in one test case, and then `4`/`1` in another test case.
- You can assume that the file chosen by a user always exists when they want to Read, Update, or Delete it.

### General rules:

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins.
  Don't let code-golf languages discourage you from posting answers with non-codegolfing languages. Try to come up with an as short as possible answer for 'any' programming language.
- [Standard rules apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422) for your answer with [default I/O rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/), so you are allowed to use STDIN/STDOUT, functions/method with the proper parameters and return-type, full programs. Your call.
- [Default Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- If possible, please add a link with a test for your code (i.e. [TIO](https://tio.run/#)).
- Also, adding an explanation for your answer is highly recommended.

### All possible test cases (where the actions can be in either input-order<sup>*†*</sup>):

<sup>*†*</sup>: You should support all (up to four) variations of the test cases below. So if a test case states `action1: Create file A; action2: Update file B`, that test case should also hold the same results for `action1: Create file B; action2: Update file A`; `action1: Update file B; action2: Create file A`; and `action1: Update file A; action2: Create file B`.

```
Valid use-cases:

locking mode: either;  action1: Create file A;  action2: Create file B
locking mode: either;  action1: Create file A;  action2: Read file B
locking mode: either;  action1: Create file A;  action2: Update file B
locking mode: either;  action1: Create file A;  action2: Delete file B
locking mode: either;  action1: Read file A;    action2: Read file A
locking mode: either;  action1: Read file A;    action2: Read file B
locking mode: either;  action1: Read file A;    action2: Update file B
locking mode: either;  action1: Read file A;    action2: Delete file B
locking mode: either;  action1: Update file A;  action2: Update file B
locking mode: either;  action1: Update file A;  action2: Delete file B
locking mode: either;  action1: Delete file A;  action2: Delete file B

Error use-cases:

locking mode: either;  action1: Create file A;  action2: Create file A
locking mode: either;  action1: Create file A;  action2: Read file A
locking mode: either;  action1: Create file A;  action2: Update file A
locking mode: either;  action1: Create file A;  action2: Delete file A
locking mode: either;  action1: Read file A;    action2: Delete file A
locking mode: on;      action1: Update file A;  action2: Update file A
locking mode: either;  action1: Update file A;  action2: Delete file A

Problem use-cases:

locking mode: either;  action1: Read file A;    action2: Update file A
locking mode: off;     action1: Update file A;  action2: Update file A
locking mode: either;  action1: Delete file A;  action2: Delete file A
```

Comment: I feel like there will be a 1 byte solution if I can just come up with the right input/output methods (maybe some kind of bit masking)

Comment: @ExpiredData Altered a few parts of the possible outputs, that they have to be consistent, but not necessarily unique. And also that the inputs have to be consistent.

Comment: @Arnauld Ah, [I excluded all `B/B` cases in my counting](https://tio.run/##bZDBTsMwDIbvfQqzw5LQEa1XpjINiSMnjlMOUZqMTl0zJS1IsD17sVtYh7pDGv@/7c@N9/pDRxPKY/NQ@8J2nYMcnA/GvqKE/Am@E4CIZm0/4c02K5RbKeXMhLaYKXnQR66XWIg@ZtiGLdgzG3x38W/0ZGNu0vcvB8DHHzqdoB@XA2sZzOdAnItwfcZlYo3EJRIzpuAR43umRI8@DK@6ggPc8aEP5/eQ7FcIUlHqoqCRKdFTmpdSSQqEElegMf6Lhpu@dIJt2lBDXCXnJNk2obULcLqKVkl834s27/zm4t1oC9q@8XX0lZWV3/EoY/k1tWnZUcm9L2vOgIlJARpn0XU/), since I deemed them similar as `A/A`. That's where the difference is coming from. But I guess that thinking is incorrectly if you have a specific value for the files..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## JavaScript (ES6), 36 bytes

#### Without a lookup table

```javascript
(m,a,f,A,F)=>f-F?2:a^A?a*A&8:a&4?m:a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZPBToNAEIbvfYo9tWCmRpseGgySQeBkSmOqJ2OytmBqgDW08fVxETEWgf1PDMOfj9nNfO/yUx535eHjNC/UPqlSt7JykpQSU2S7t@k88haOfGFPXvB05cjp0ssdWe1UcTyJeC1ccUUijiJdrEhw8@7rxzWJu4eQt2HT0mWgqwWJx03QdJckgvA@/K5XN5NJzVRZcpmpN2v2JLPD3pnZZ93Uitckfrj6b/Rb@va/ZBQRmOww61F1B2COJDvM5tDInCPJDrO5PIQ5kqyZ7TH@nIj7mVhygOnDTPOchvvEkh2m4T6xZM1sf2meE0t2mIY5sWTNbD@bmQPJc2Wfi7AsVYlLy7C0DEvLsLQMS8uwtAxLy7C0DC8uw4vL8OIyvI4MryP3rM6mVK9Zkg8sT4/PDJvPsHsMe8KwJzpZfQE)

#### I/O

- Locking mode (\$m\$): \$0\$ = On, \$8\$ = Off
- Actions (\$a\$ and \$A\$): \$0\$ = Create, \$2\$ = Read, \$4\$ = Update, \$8\$ = Delete
- Files (\$f\$ and \$F\$): any integers
- Output: \$0\$ = Error,  \$2\$ = Valid, \$8\$ = Problem

#### How?

If the files are different, all operations are safe and we just return \$2\$ (valid).

If the files are identical, we need to return:

- \$2\$ (valid) if we have two *read* operations
- \$8\$ (problem) if we have two *delete* operations, or one *update* and one *read*
- \$m\$ (either problem or error) if we have two *update* operations
- \$0\$ (error) for everything else

Using a \$4\times4\$ CRUD matrix (which is symmetric by definition), we can see that the above values can be computed with:

$$\underbrace{\text{a ^ A}}_{a\neq A?}\text{ ? }\color{blue}{\text{a * A & 8}}\text{ : }\underbrace{\text{a & 4}}_{\text{update?}}\text{ ? }\color{red}{\text{m}} : \color{magenta}{\text{a}}$$

$$\begin{array}{cc|cccc}
&&\text{C}&\text{R}&\text{U}&\text{D}\\
&&0&2&4&8\\
\hline
\text{C}&0&\color{magenta}{0}&\color{blue}{0}&\color{blue}{0}&\color{blue}{0}\\
\text{R}&2&\color{blue}{0}&\color{magenta}{2}&\color{blue}{8}&\color{blue}{0}\\
\text{U}&4&\color{blue}{0}&\color{blue}{8}&\color{red}{\text{m}}&\color{blue}{0}\\
\text{D}&8&\color{blue}{0}&\color{blue}{0}&\color{blue}{0}&\color{magenta}{8}
\end{array}$$

---

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>46 45</s>  40 bytes

#### With a lookup table

```javascript
(m,a,f,A,F)=>f-F?0:[m,1,1,0][a*2+A*9&23]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZNBT4NAEIXv/RV7slC3htKTNWgGYU@mNEa91B6wgMFQ1tDq38elFGMR2BcODMPLt7OT9z7C73C/LdLPwzSXUVwmTmnseMgTTlyYzm0yFXfWYr3jM/VYm3U4sS9pcn1hzzflVub7AwuWzGFfeRQnaR5HnAVCqMaMM1IvizO3/npeefTk161Hn7y6e6/KY9fmzPMf/GM9vxmNKrbM4qtMvhvjlzBLo8XYPOsmRrDk7ERQp/Hf0jX/KYXgoLLFrEZVHYA5oGwx61Ugcw4oW8x6eQhzQFkxm2v8uRF1MzFlD9OFmfo5NfvElC2mZp@YsmI2R@rnxJQtpmZOTFkxm996Zo/yPLKvuV8UssBDS3BoCQ4twaElOLQEh5bg0BIcWoKNS7BxCTYuwXYk2I7UYZ1VId@yeNdjno48E5x8grNHcE4IzolSlj8)

#### I/O

- Locking mode: *undefined* = On, \$1\$ = Off
- Actions: \$0\$ = Update, \$1\$ = Read, \$2\$ = Create, \$3\$ = Delete
- Files: any integers
- Output: *undefined* = Error, \$0\$ = Valid, \$1\$ = Problem

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 53 bytes

```
^(.)(?!\1).+|..RR.
V
..DD.
P
..UUL
E
.+[CD].+
E
..+
P
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hc07CgJBEIThfG5hIOyy0OAJZGtHTCZYGtrEBxoYmBiIoXcfZ/6kuij46M/z@3o/6nY43uttsHHYby670aafmbulUzLL2dLabkRJh2TTeclXm3ptudY6z8sSqaWTQeaezuIszhL0oOeewgorrLDCCiussMIK2/4W/pJB5sJfksVZgh703FNYYYUVVlhhhRVW2Pa3/AE) Link includes test suite. Takes input as a string of 5 characters, two characters representing the file names, then two characters from `CRUD`, then `L` or `U` (locked/unlocked), and outputs one of `VPE` (valid/problem/error). Explanation:

```
^(.)(?!\1).+|..RR.
V
```

Different file names are always valid, as are two reads. Annoyingly, this is the only test that forces me to use a header. (It would cost an extra byte to make the header unnecessary.)

```
..DD.
P
```

Two deletes are always a problem.

```
..UUL
E
```

Two locked updates are an error.

```
.+[CD].+
E
```

Any other creates or deletes are an error.

```
..+
P
```

Everything else is a problem.

Answer (score 3):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 96 bytes

```matlab
@(a,b,c)[a(1)!=b(1)|a(2)+b(2)==20,mod((m=a+b+c)(2),10010)<1|mod(m(2),1020000)<1|mod(m(2),200)<1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYqxDoQwDEN/pbclalQlnYnEfyCGtAdbxXJi4t9LKNN5sOVnH/Vn59b3oCGl1GcwKlRxMRD8aHG/DDLG4qaamdrxBWhqscSKDkmYhXGS61naSzK7/lgefe07LOKHlUZ4BhnffgM)

Definitely can be shorter, but I don't have time right now to do that

```matlab
File 1 = 0
File 2 = 1
Read = 10
Delete = 100
Create = 1000 
Update = 10000
Lock on = 100000
Lock off = 1000000

Valid Values: 
[1 0] 

Problem Values: 
[0 1]


Invalid Values: 
[0 0]
```

Input as a = [file, action], b = [file2, action2], c = lock